# MongoDB driver PHP interaction with Mongo driver for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, driver, php-mongodb

I am currently using the MongoDB driver for PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

However I would also like to be able to use the legacy driver (Mongo for PHP) for compatibility purposes:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

Is there any way that I could use both at the same time in the same PHP script?

Comment: If both support your desired PHP version, I don't see a reason why you couldn't. They're not in conflict with each other as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possibility is to use a wrapper, you can find some thing here [PHP MongoDB Frameworks](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php-libraries/)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about such a possibility.